# Django serializer for one object

Tags: django, serialization, json

```
res = {'name':'man','surname':'seal'}
encoded = json.dumps(res)
return render_to_response('example.html',{'encoded':encoded} )
```

example.html

```
{{ encoded }}
```

This code is work fine. Returned:

```
{'name':'man','surname':'seal'}
```

But i wanna only name variable:

```
man
```

how can i make ?  {{ encoded.name }} is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
res = {'name':'man','surname':'seal'}
encoded = json.loads(json.dumps(res))
return render_to_response('example.html',{'encoded':encoded} )
```

and then this should show what you want -

```
Surname = {{ encoded.surname }}
Name  = {{ encoded.name }}
```

Comment: Hi this code working successful but if i change res = http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TWXSX3Vm this dict i have error ?

Comment: Make sure you're giving it valid json. What you have in this url is not valid - use jsonlint.com to validate.

Comment: i __dict__ this object and save my data base :/

Comment: You probably want to dumps it and save to db, not dict.